# How to use variable values from one method to another method in C#?

Tags: c#

In my code I am using two `button_Click` methods. I want to use values of some variables from the first method in the other. E.g.: I want to use values of `h` and `w` of defined in `button1_Click` in `button2_Click`. Is it possible?

```
public int h, w;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Text = "Image Path here ...";
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Title = "Select an Image";
    dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    if (DialogResult.OK == dlg.ShowDialog())
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
        int w = img.Width;
        int h = img.Height;
        pictureBox1.Height = h;
        pictureBox1.Width = w;
        textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;
    }
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Height is- " + h.ToString() + " Width is- " + w.ToString(), "Height & Width");
}
```

Comment: You should learn to write maintainable code (for ex. `textbox1` is not very descriptive)...  and remove useless code like creating a `Bitmap` twice. And you should also use `String.Format` to format your text. And properly indent text. And you should set message box title and icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `button1_Click` you are not assigning to the `h` and `w` of the class, but to local variables. Just change

```
 int w = img.Width;
 int h = img.Height;
```

to

```
 w = img.Width;
 h = img.Height;
```

and it should work, if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.